# Restart explorer when prompt is started as adminstrator on windows 8 don't work

Tags: windows, batch-file, prompt, explorer

I need to restart `explorer.exe` after my application is installed. I'm currently using:

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

That works ok on windows 7, with administrator or standard user, but when I try this on windows 8 as a standard user, the command just kills the explorer and doesn't restart it.

This happens because the command line is called as administrator, even with the standard user. Then the explorer doesn't restart.

Any thoughts about how to solve this?

Comment: What are you doing that requires you to kill the shell? Perhaps there is a less heavy handed mechanism.

Comment: I need to register some dlls for icon overlays, that will appear only when the explorer restarts

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your problem. Is there anything else running on the system that might be keeping explorer from starting? Are you double-clicking the script or running it from the command prompt? Windows 8 or 8.1?

Comment: Both windows 8 and 8.1. If I log in the standard user and run the prompt as administrator, then I can kill the explorer, but when I use the start explorer.exe, I don't get any response

Comment: Why does your installer not prompt user for confirmation on restarting Windows, and when getting a positive confirmation, perform the Windows restart as most other installers do in such cases?

Comment: I finally did this, was the only way that I found.

Answer (score 1):

The code should work but since I'm not using win8 (no thanks) can not diagnose.
But some I can offer.
This may work (time needed to unload some handlers) And double tried with or without start (yes it differs in some software, don't know win8)

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
timeout 7
start "" explorer.exe
timeout 2
explorer.exe
```

explorer.exe keeps many handlers, shell stuff etc. One of those can cause trouble. Try also to disable them and test again

If not you can also try [reexplorer tool](http://www.sordum.org/8098/some-small-tools/) to do the same. Maybe they considered this kind of situations while coding.

All bests

Comment: I decided by ask the user to restart the computer. I also tried the code that you posted, didn't work.
Thanks for the advice on reexplorer tool.